# Is it possible to change the speech rate in OS X say command?

Tags: macos, command-line, osx-mavericks, text-to-speech

```
say -v Alex "Hello"
```

Is there a way to change the speed of speech like there is in the speech settings of *System Preferences* -> *Date & Time* -> *Clock* -> *Customize Voice*?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, there is.  The command

```
say -v Alex "Hello" -r 200
```

will cause the voice Alex say "Hello" at a rate of 200 words/minute.

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out (with no rudeness intended) that this is easily found in the manpage for `say`.  `man [programname]` will bring up the documentation for most unix command line applications.

Comment: `-r  --rate=` wasn't working for me on 10.13 for `/usr/bin/say`, but the embedded speech command below did.  Was using `-v Tom`.

Comment: What is the default rate?

Comment: @FelixJassler The default rate is 200

Answer (score 10):

There is also an [embedded speech command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/FineTuning/FineTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH5-SW3) for changing the rate:

```
say '[[rate 200]] hello'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the new voices added by Apple since 10.6 will ignore embedded commands for speech rates and phoneme preferences. :( Really annoying, since I love the Fiona voice pack, but she occasionally mis-pronounces some words so horribly that they're unrecognisable. :(

Comment: Interestingly, this works in HTML documents with Apple Speech Synthesis hotkey and the JS Speech Synthesis API.

Comment: Seems to work as of 10.12, even with the very realistic voices like Thomas. Super creepy at 40 wpm :D

Comment: doesn't seem work (nor does `--rate` with localized voices such as Luca and Alice) on 10.14

Comment: It's okay with me to use `say "[[rate +500]] hello"` ;)  As the document says.

Comment: I'm on 11.5 and the + added by @wind2412 is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: Interesting thing to note is that this method only changes the speed in increments of 50 wpm, unlike the `--rate` flag

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I'm on Big Sur and the `-r`/`--rate` is simply ignored. However, the embedded command as described by [@lri](https://superuser.com/users/69039/lri) still works.

P.S. I see in an earlier comment that 10.13 also had that issue. Well...