# macos: How do you change the accessibility's speech rate so that it's faster than the default maximum?

Tags: macos, accessibility, text-to-speech

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/679099/is-it-possible-to-change-the-speech-rate-in-os-x-say-command) is what I'm kind of looking for, but it only works in the terminal.  Is there a `defaults write` command that allows you to change the speech rate?

Answer (score 0):

So what I understand is that you need your Mac to speak faster when using the normal "start speaking" command (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)? If so, I made a [video explaining how to do this with a workflow](https://youtu.be/0-tWT7SOq-4) and also [how to troubleshoot that](https://youtu.be/cR5i7D2Pzf8).

Essentially, I use an [automator workflow](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OhE_oYfC8qWNHGj6Rqj_g1VxiVtmBPux/view?usp=sharing) that gives terminal the commands from [this stack exchange post](https://superuser.com/questions/1051883/speed-up-rate-of-text-to-speech-via-terminal). The post uses this script:

```
plutil -convert json ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist -o - |
python -c 'import json, sys;d=json.load(sys.stdin);[x.__setitem__(-1, 500) for x in d["VoiceRateDataArray"]];json.dump(d, sys.stdout)' |
plutil -convert binary1 -o ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist -
```

which I modified to work in automator (it looks like this):

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "defaults read com.apple.speech.voice.prefs VoiceRateDataArray 
plutil -convert json ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist -o - | python -c 'import json, sys;d=json.load(sys.stdin);[x.__setitem__(-1, " & (the clipboard) & ") for x in d[\"VoiceRateDataArray\"]];json.dump(d, sys.stdout)' | plutil -convert binary1 -o ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.speech.voice.prefs.plist - 

sleep 1
killall com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd
killall SpeechSynthesisServer && exit
" in front window
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

The end goal being a workflow (posted above) to give the user a simpler experience with the same capabilities as the terminal command.

In summary, I built an automator workflow that does what you want it to do. If you don't understand any of this post, just watch the video (first link).